# How to download FASTA sequences from NCBI using the terminal?

Tags: fasta, phylogenetics, linux

I have following accession numbers of the 10 chromosomes of *Theobroma cacao* genome.

```
NC_030850.1
NC_030851.1
NC_030852.1
NC_030853.1
NC_030854.1
NC_030855.1
NC_030856.1
NC_030857.1
NC_030858.1
NC_030859.1
```

I need to download these FASTA files using the terminal because I'm working on a server. I'll be grateful if someone can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the **NCBI Entrez Direct UNIX E-utilities**

Basically, you have to download the install file here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/bin/install-edirect.sh

In the terminal, install it using: `source ./install-edirect.sh`

Then, you can download your sequence by doing:

`esearch -db nucleotide -query "NC_030850.1" | efetch -format fasta > NC_030850.1.fasta`

And you should find your fasta sequence downloaded.

As you have several sequences to download, I think it will be quite easy to add this command into a little bash script to process all of them.

More readings about that: http://bioinformatics.cvr.ac.uk/blog/ncbi-entrez-direct-unix-e-utilities/ and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/

Comment: Thank you very much for all the support.

Comment: @MudithMMBc, you're welcome ;)

Comment: @MudithMMBc Try to get a `NCBI_API_KEY` for batch downloading with `GNU parallel` at a max rate of 10 sequences/s. Then save accessions in one file and run `parallel -a accession.txt -j8 'efetch -db nuccore -id {} -format fasta >{}.fa'`. Adjust `-j8` to `-j3` if you do not have a key.

Answer (score 4):

Just `wget` or `curl` each as `https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_030853.1?report=fasta&log$=seqview&format=text`...

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to work (any longer?). For instance, `curl -L 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_030853.1?report=fasta&log$=seqview&format=text'` downloads a HTML page with an (invisible) form on it, not a FASTA file.

Answer (score 2):

### Downloading entire genomes

The best way to download FASTA sequences for an entire genome is to search for the genome, for example `Theobroma cacao genome` in the [NCBI Assembly](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/assembly) portal and use the big blue Download button. 
[image]

### Downloading individual chromosomes

For a given assembly, if you want to download the FASTA sequences for a bunch of chromosomes, you can do that by going to the Genomes FTP path highlighted in the screenshot:
[image]
Once you are in the Genomes FTP path, you can navigate to the FASTA folder as follows: 
[Theobroma FTP directory](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/403/535/GCA_000403535.1_Theobroma_cacao_20110822) >> [Assembly Structure](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/403/535/GCA_000403535.1_Theobroma_cacao_20110822/GCA_000403535.1_Theobroma_cacao_20110822_assembly_structure/) >> [Primary Assembly](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/403/535/GCA_000403535.1_Theobroma_cacao_20110822/GCA_000403535.1_Theobroma_cacao_20110822_assembly_structure/Primary_Assembly/) >> [Assembled Chromosomes](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/403/535/GCA_000403535.1_Theobroma_cacao_20110822/GCA_000403535.1_Theobroma_cacao_20110822_assembly_structure/Primary_Assembly/assembled_chromosomes/) >> [FASTA](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/000/403/535/GCA_000403535.1_Theobroma_cacao_20110822/GCA_000403535.1_Theobroma_cacao_20110822_assembly_structure/Primary_Assembly/assembled_chromosomes/FASTA/).

### Downloading a few sequences

For this, you can use [Entrez Direct](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/) as mentioned by @dc37. Why not always use Entrez Direct? While it is fine for a small number of sequences, it can be slow to download a large number of sequences. Entrez Direct by default will download uncompressed data so you will end up spending more time downloading a larger file instead of downloading a smaller, compressed file from FTP more quickly.

If you were to use Entrez Direct for this purpose, I'd not bother with a bash script and use `epost` to first post the entire list of accessions and then pipe it to `efetch` as shown below:

```
epost -db nuccore -input <file_with_accs> -format acc \
  | efetch -format fasta > sequences.fasta
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the support.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to [the main FASTA sequence page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_030853.1?report=fasta&log$=seqview&format=text...), view source, and get the "ncbi_uidlist" value.  In this case, it's `1061361601`
2. Use the ID in the query string to download directly:

   https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=**1061361601**&db=nuccore&report=fasta&retmode=text&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=100000000

You can also get this link directly, by using Chrome's developer tools (F12), viewing the Network tab, then loading the page in (1).

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I can't post a comment with my reputation score). 
@vkkodali, interesting command I did not know about it ;). However, your command is downloading all sequences from the input file into a single fasta file. I believe that if you have a big bunch of sequences, it could be a little bit tricky after to manipulate that kind of file. Just by curiosity, do you have a trick to create one sequence per file using `efetch` ?

Comment: If you have a big bunch of sequences, you will end up with a lot of files. Whether you want a large number of files or just one file is, I guess, a personal choice. A multifasta file is fairly standard though. I don't think you can create individual files for each sequence using `epost` and `efetch`; you will have to either use a bash script or postprocess the `efetch` output using the unix tool `split`.

Comment: Ok, I understand it. Thanks for your thoughts ;)